# How to edit hosts file via CMD?

Tags: windows-7, cmd, hosts

Hello I'd like to block some websites directly from the command prompt.

echo like this:

```
0.0.0.0 websitename.com
```

How can I do this? (OS: Windows 7)

Comment: Why close such a brilliant question?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`echo 0.0.0.0 websitename.com >> %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts`

the `>>` appends the output of `echo` to the file.

Note that there are two reasons this might not work like you want it to. You may be aware of these, but I mention them just in case.

First, it won't affect a web browser, for example, that already has the current, "real" IP address resolved. So, it won't always take effect right away.

Second, it requires you to add an entry for every host name on a domain; just adding `websitename.com` will *not* block `www.websitename.com`, for example.

Comment: How can I add a list of entries then?

Comment: @omnix : just keep adding multiple entries

Comment: a `ipconfig /flushdns` will make your changes to this file take effect immediately

Comment: Does this work from the "Execute" prompt? What's the correct way to enter ipconfig / flushdns? I do not have windows and need to forward that to someone.

Comment: @shredding Not sure what you mean by the "Execute prompt". If you mean the command prompt, well yes; that's what the question was. And I don't know what you mean by 'correct' way to run `ipconfig /flushdns`. That can also just be run from the command prompt.

Comment: I meant are `ipconfig / flushdns` two comments two be executed on two lines? And yes, I meant the command prompt :)

Comment: @shredding  `ipconfig /flushdns` is a single command with an argument.

Comment: Perfect! Works even during PXE installation where ServaBoot machine name could not be resolved.

Answer (score 25):

Use **Hosts Commander**. It's simple and powerful. You can download it [here](https://veg.by/en/projects/hostscmd/).

## Examples of using

```
hosts add another.dev 192.168.1.1 # Remote host
hosts add test.local # 127.0.0.1 used by default
hosts set myhost.dev # new comment
hosts rem *.local
hosts enable local*
hosts disable localhost
```

...and many others...

## Help

```
Usage:
    hosts - run hosts command interpreter
    hosts <command> <params> - execute hosts command

Commands:
    add  <host> <aliases> <addr> # <comment>   - add new host
    set  <host|mask> <addr> # <comment>        - set ip and comment for host
    rem  <host|mask>   - remove host
    on   <host|mask>   - enable host
    off  <host|mask>   - disable host
    view [all] <mask>  - display enabled and visible, or all hosts
    hide <host|mask>   - hide host from 'hosts view'
    show <host|mask>   - show host in 'hosts view'
    print      - display raw hosts file
    format     - format host rows
    clean      - format and remove all comments
    rollback   - rollback last operation
    backup     - backup hosts file
    restore    - restore hosts file from backup
    recreate   - empty hosts file
    open       - open hosts file in notepad
```