# How to run two local web development projects in xampp

Tags: html, web, xampp, localhost, virtualhost

I am working on two different web development projects say A and B. I put all the project-A files in C:\xampp\htdocs\A and similarly all the project-B files in C:\xampp\htdocs\B. Sometimes I need to work on both the projects *without switching work space*. I am able to see the websites running on `localhost:8080` one at a time. How can I run both websites at same time without switching work space? I would like to access the website `A.localhost` and `B.localhost` in browser?

I have done some research and found that there is a concept called Virtual Hosts in XAMPP. But not able to implement properly, also I tried the same via this tutorial but the browser displayed `dns_unresolved_hostname` issue. Can someone provide exact steps to implement this setup in XAMPP.

This is my project structure:

C:\xampp\htdocs\A - index.html, style.css etc for ProjectA

C:\xampp\htdocs\B - index.html, style.css etc for ProjectB

Comment: Have you modified your `hosts` file? [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222045/how-to-edit-hosts-file-via-cmd)

Answer (score 2):

```
    # Setup Listening Port
NameVirtualHost *:8080

# Ensure "localhost" is preserved
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName a.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
</VirtualHost>

# Setup "a.localhost" Virtual Host
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName b.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\B"

    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\B">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
# Setup "a.localhost" Virtual Host
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName a.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\A"

    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\A">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And open `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`
Add theses lines at end

```
127.0.0.1  a.localhost
127.0.0.1  b.localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows 
 
**Step: 1** 
Open this file `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` with any text editor **(administrative privileges not required)**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\public"
   ServerName project1.test
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\project2\public"
   ServerName project2.test
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step: 2** 
Open this file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` with any text editor **(administrative privileges required)**

```
127.0.0.1 project1.test
127.0.0.1 project2.test
```

Now restart Xampp